# Flutter - How to delete text after last '/' in string

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help transforming this:

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/testapp/files/textToDelete

into this

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/testapp/files/

note: I don't want to use static value substring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// the string to be trimmed
var myString = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/testapp/files/textToDelete';

// substring the string using the last index of the character + 1
var trimmedString = myString.substring(0, myString.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

// print the trimmed string
print(trimmedString);
```

OUTPUT:
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/testapp/files/

Answer (score 0):

Used

```dart
.substring(0, var.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

and that worked perfectly

Comment: The last `/` character will still be present @Fifcio, take a look at your question again.

Comment: Your question says you want to output `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/testapp/files/` but your answer outputs `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/testapp/files`